# Как скачать конкретного профиля фото профиля через Telethon?

Tags: python, парсер, api, telegram, telethon

Есть массив данных об конкретном пользователе, где: `0`, `1`, `2` - это порядок.

```
0 - User(id=424322805
1 - is_self=False
2 - contact=True
3 - mutual_contact=False
4 - deleted=False
5 - bot=False
6 - bot_chat_history=False
7 - bot_nochats=False
8 - verified=False
9 - restricted=False
10 - min=False
11 - bot_inline_geo=False
12 - support=False
13 - scam=False
14 - access_hash=2832310685690367355
15 - first_name='Наскаанттка'
16 - last_name=None
17 - username='Anaк3уaGrigorovich'
18 - phone='332426211410'
19 - photo=UserProfilePhoto(photo_id=182543423285424308
20 - photo_small=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(volume_id=257435025
21 - local_id=392782)
22 - photo_big=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(volume_id=2542425
23 - local_id=3932484)
24 - dc_id=2
25 - has_video=False)
26 - status=UserStatusOffline(was_online=datetime.datetime(2020
27 - 10
28 - 22
29 - 12
30 - 39
31 - 43
32 - tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))
33 - bot_info_version=None
34 - restriction_reason=[]
35 - bot_inline_placeholder=None
36 - lang_code=None
```

Как скачать фотографию профиля в нормальной размере и малом размере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для скачивания используйте метод [download_profile_photo](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/c864ef7e16565c08362e3d01b8a60ecb3bf6c31c/telethon/client/downloads.py#L184), а для получения превью указывайте параметр `download_big=False`.

Пример:

```
# pip install telethon
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

from config import API_ID, API_HASH

with TelegramClient('my', API_ID, API_HASH) as client:
    print('Picture big:', client.download_profile_photo('me'))
    print('Picture small:', client.download_profile_photo('me', download_big=False))
```

---

**PS.**

Можно в сам [download_profile_photo](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/c864ef7e16565c08362e3d01b8a60ecb3bf6c31c/telethon/client/downloads.py#L184) передавать название файла через параметр `file`, например:

```
client.download_profile_photo('me', 'img.jpg')

# Или:
client.download_profile_photo('me', file='img.jpg')
```

Comment: отлично, как скачать фото не свое а конкретного другого пользователя исходя из данных которые есть выше?

Comment: Вместо `me` укажите username например `"@Anaк3уaGrigorovich"` или id пользователя